# Android Studio with Git: Pulled changes showing in Local changes window Default Changelist?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, version-control

I am new to co-working with Git. I am working with Android Studio 3.5 together with another developer. He is working on a branch "feature x". I am working on a sub-branch of this branch, called "feature x part 2". I am doing my commits and pushes whenever I think I have to.

Now after some time, I need some of the changes my co-worker did on branch "feature x". So I am doing a

1. git commit and push to save all my changes to my remote branch
2. git pull and select my branch and the "feature x" branch to be merged into my branch

**After I did this, I see all the changes my co-worker did in my "Local Changes" window under "Default Changelist"** which gets me confused: I never edited those files but now they are shown in blue (edited) and green (added) so when I do my next commit/push, I will push them to my branch.

I reenacted the scenario at home and here the situation is different: pulled changes from "feature x" branch are NOT shown in Local Changes (but are pulled and shown correctly). Is there any setting I am not aware of?